# C# HttpRequest posting a URL

Tags: c#, httprequest, url-parameters

I'm trying to get an HttpRequest to post this URL

https://www.iformbuilder.com/exzact/_emptyTable.php?PAGE_ID=1234&TABLE_NAME=table_name_here&USERNAME=yo@yo.com&PASSWORD=What!What!

I've tried using

```
WebClient rar = new WebClient();
rar.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(@"https://www.iformbuilder.com/exzact/_emptyTable.php?PAGE_ID=1234&TABLE_NAME=table_name_here&USERNAME=yo@yo.com&PASSWORD=What!What!"));

rar.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(@"https://www.iformbuilder.com/exzact/_emptyTable.php?PAGE_ID=1234&TABLE_NAME=table_name_here&USERNAME=yo@yo.com&PASSWORD=What!What!"));
```

This is suppose to delete my information on their site, but it's not taking. i'm following this documentation.
http://getsatisfaction.com/exzact/topics/how_can_we_delete_old_records_not_manually

and they state that all I have to do is paste the proper URL into a web browser and hit enter and it will work. How would I do this equivalent in c#? Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to escape all of those forward slashes.

Comment: @Nick: 1) Why would one need to escape *forward* slashes. 2) If they were *back* slashes they would *already* be escaped by the `@` in front of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx) instead of DownloadStringAsync. Async indicates asynchronous methods that do not block the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your User-Agent header in your WebClient before you submit it to see if that fixes things.

`rar.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)")`

A lot of web servers are set up to simply ignore requests if the User-Agent header is missing.

Subsequently, you're using HTTPS here so you'll want to set up your `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use System.Web classes, for example like this:

```
        HttpWebRequest req = null;
        HttpWebResponse resp = null;

        try
        {
            req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url); // enter your url

            req.Method = "post";

            resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

It's example for post method, you can use any other HTTP method like this. Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question but check out [Hammock for REST](http://hammock.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         string uriString = @"https://www.iformbuilder.com/exzact/_emptyTable.php?PAGE_ID=1234&TABLE_NAME=table_name_here&USERNAME=yo@yo.com&PASSWORD=What!What!";
>         using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 })
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 string content = webClient.DownloadString(uriString);
>                 //do stuff with the answer you got back from the site
>             }
>             catch (Exception exception)
>             {
>                 //handle exceptions
>             }
>         }
> ```